# Compile errors when trying to use list in C++

Tags: c++, list

I'm trying to use list in c++, but I get the following error:

> 1>error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>
> 1>error C4430: missing type specifier int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>
> 1>error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

With the following code:

```
#pragma once

#include "Includes.h"

class Polygon
{
public:
    Polygon(void);
    ~Polygon(void);

    void addVertice(hgeVector v);
    void renderPolygon();
    list<hgeVector> vertices;
};
```

Includes.h:

```
#ifndef INCLUDES
#define INCLUDES

#define safe_delete(d) if(d) { delete d; d=0; }
#define PI 3.14159
#include <stdio.h>
#include <list>
#include "\include\hge.h"
#include "\include\hgesprite.h"
#include "\include\hgefont.h"
#include "\include\hgeparticle.h"
#include "\include\hgerect.h"
#include "Car.h"
#include "HelperFunctions.h"
#include "config.h"
#include "Polygon.h"

using namespace std;

#endif
```

Comment: For what it's worth, `safe_delete` is a terrible idea. It'll mask logic issues inside your code. Use smart pointers (e.g. `boost::scoped_ptr`, `boost::shared_ptr`, `boost::scoped_array` or `boost::shared_array`) instead.

Comment: Why even bother with the `if(d)` in the safe delete?

Comment: @Per `safe_delete` is useless actually, it is safe to delete a null pointer!

Comment: @AraK - I think the point for the safe_delete is not to avoi delete null piointer, but to set the pointer to null after it is deleted - which is a good practice.

But if(d) is useless - as you said, it is OK to delete a null ptr.

Comment: Not to mention all of the standard "macros are evil" ways in which things could go wrong when using the given implementation of `safe_delete`: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.4

Comment: is <list> found by the compiler? some compilers, e.g. gcc, issue a warning only (for some reason I can't see) when they fail on #include. the errors "sound like" the list type is not known to the compiler. can you check this, e.g. comment out the #include <list> line and see if errors change? BTW, on what line the errors are given?

Comment: All three of them are given at the line: polygon.h(13)
That is this line: list<hgeVector> vertices;

@davka When I remove #include <list> it complains. I'm using Visual C++ express edition 2008

Comment: @Findekano: I don't believe in this being a good practice. A pointer should be out of scope right after the object it pointed to was deleted. If you do so (or better yet, if you use smart pointers), you'll never need to assign `NULL` to them after `delete`.

Comment: re safe_delete, here's how Stroustrup suggests to do it:
`template<class T> inline void destroy(T*& p) { delete p; p = 0; }`

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#delete-zero

Comment: @davka: Not that he writes right after that: "Consider this yet-another reason to minimize explicit use of new and delete by relying on standard library containers, handles, etc"

Comment: @Per - is your first file poligon.h? I see that it is included in the includes.h. First, it creates a cycle that is confusing (at least for me :),  but moreover it is included before the `using namespace std` is reached. Try `std::list`.

In general, `using namespace ...` in .h files is considered (by some) a bad practice, so I'd move it to the corresponding .cpp file

Comment: @sbi - yes, I saw it, I believe that by "this" he means the fact that the operand of delete is not zeroed, not the destroy function he suggests. Just renaming delete to destroy wouldn't qualify as "minimizing explicit use of new and delete..." :)

Comment: @sbi: Yes, sure - it is a best practice in thoery though. With all good wishes, there are still tons of legacy code, and the ugly fact that we have to deal with pointers sometimes. You code might be maintaned by others, and it might be after 10 years. The name of the pointer may still in scope after it is deleted. Thus always set the pointer to NULL immediately after it is deleted IS a good practice. In practical it saved me a lot of debugging time.

Comment: @Findekano: "In practical it [zeroing pointers after delete] saved me a lot of debugging time." I never did it and I can't remember when I had to debug a stray pointer last time. But I most likely haven't written a manual `delete` ten times within the last decade...

Answer (score 7):

Just some general comments...

```
 #define PI 3.14159
```

Please use `M_PI` in `math.h`, which is 3.141592653589793238462643.

```
#include "\include\hge.h"
#include "\include\hgesprite.h"
#include "\include\hgefont.h"
#include "\include\hgeparticle.h"
#include "\include\hgerect.h"
```

You should use forward slashes `/` here, and remove the leading `\` before the `include`.

```
using namespace std;
```

Avoid this in header file. This will pollute all other users' global namespace. (Therefore, you should use `std::list<hgeVector> vertices;` in `Polygon.h`.)

Answer (score 5):

The issue could be that the line `list<hgeVector> vertices` is being processed before `using namespace std;`, and so your compiler does not know what a `list` (without the `std::` namespace qualifier) is. It's not clear to me in exactly what order these statements get processed since your two files include each other, and I don't know precisely how the non-standard `#pragma once` will handle this.

**In any case, try qualifying `list<hgeVector>` as `std::list<hgeVector>`**

Edit: Assuming `#pragma once` works just like include guards, then this problem will occur if some other file inlcudes includes.h, but not if some other file includes Polygon.h. If another file includes includes.h, what happens is that includes.h reaches `#include <Polygon.h>`, and the compiler starts processing Polygon.h. But then when `#include <includes.h>` is reached inside Polygon.h, nothing is effectively included since the `INCLUDES` guard is already defined, so you don't get the `using namespace std;` line before the compiler continues processing the rest of Polygons.h.

In general, try to avoid circular inclusion, and prefer forward-declarations.

Comment: Did you mean "forward-declarations"?

Comment: Thanks alot!
It worked after putting std:: before list<hgeVector>

Answer (score 4):

I think you have circular "includes". You are including `Includes.h` in `Polygon.h` and including `Polygon.h` in `Includes.h`.

Comment: If there is a guardance marco, or 'pragma once', this is not a problem, right?

Comment: That might well be the problem. `#pragma once` should protect against this, but perhaps it isn't.

Comment: The problem *is* the include guards. Think about exactly what happens with respect to the `using namespace std` line and the `list<hgeVector>` line when a third file writes `#include <includes.h>`

Comment: should I include "polygon.h" in polygon.cpp and include "Includes.h" in polygon.h?

EDIT: It did not solve the problem.

Comment: OP should be using MSVC, which supports `#pragma once`.

Comment: Yes, and you should not include `polygon.h` (or any other file with an `#include <includes.h>` directive) in `includes.h`.

Comment: @Tyler Why? I'm using the includes.h in all of my files.

Comment: The problem you are having is stemming from circular inclusion (where two files each include each other). Read my answer to this question that explains why you reach the `list<hgVector>` line before the `using namespace std` line when a third file includes `includes.h`. In general, circular inclusion is a bad thing because it causes confusing issues like this.

Comment: @AraK: Good catch. I thought this smelled of circular includes, but I thought it was too little information and didn't even bother looking close. You had a very good eye there... +1

Answer (score 1):

class template need a full type declaration to instantiate itself. Make sure you have included the header file where hgeVector is declared.

BTW, you have 'using namespace std‘ in your header  - this is not a good practice. It will introduce unnecessary names to the current namespace.

Comment: It's _class template_, not template class (because it's a template from which classes are instantiated, not the other way around).

Comment: Thanks - it is always difficult to figure out the subtle English terms for a non-native English speaker. I have fixed it.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that `using namespace std;` in headers is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `hgeVector` is defined.

You may have redefined list somewhere. Try using `std::list`.

Try something very simple like `std::list<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer (as Tyler McHenry pointed out) was circular inclusion!

After sorting out my includes I ended up with a compiled code like this (even without std:: infront of list:

```
#pragma once

#include <list>
#include "D:\Programmering\haffes\hge181\include\hge.h"
#include "D:\Programmering\haffes\hge181\include\hgevector.h"
using namespace std;

using namespace std;

class MyPolygon
{
public:
    MyPolygon(void);
    ~MyPolygon(void);

    void addVertice(hgeVector v);
    void renderPolygon();
    void setHotSpot(hgeVector v);
    void translate(hgeVector v);
private:
    list<hgeVector> vertices;
    hgeVector hotSpot;
    bool hotSpotUndef;
};
```

Thanks a bunch for all the fast and good answers!

Comment: Avoiding stuff like `#include "D:\Programmering\haffes\hge181\include\hge.h"` is why compilers support using `-I directory` to add it to the include path. Then the code compiles even if it's located somewhere else.